# What is the alternative of componentDidMount in a functional component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have a RN app that has a home screen with different chats. When the user taps on a chat, it's messages are loaded from the local db and displayed. Like Whatsapp does, I want to preload messages and scroll to the last message before the screen is actually loaded. I have tried loading messages in `useEffect` with an empty dependency array but the messages are shown after the screen is loaded. So the user sees a glitch. I want to avoid that glitch. I have also tried to use `useFocusEffect` with no effect.

Comment: "I want to preload messages and scroll to the last message before the screen is actually loaded" What do you want to do until then? Hang on the previous screen?

Comment: Are you using a routing framework for this? i.e. React Router?

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev I am looking for any event if available that is trigged before the screen is actually loaded/mounted. This is the place I can preload messages. Just how Whatsap is doing it. I know it's optimistic but I know we can achieve this somehow

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev I am using React Native's React Navigation

Comment: I still don't understand. Let's say it takes 2 seconds to load the messages. What should the user see between pressing on a chat and it displaying the messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try settimeout with useffect  hook and loading usestate

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text, FlatList, InteractionManager } from 'react-native';

function ChatScreen({ route }) {
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions(() => {
       setTimeout(() => {
        const fetchedMessages = [
         //use your code here  
        ];
        setMessages(fetchedMessages);
        setLoading(false);
      }, 1000);
    });
  }, []);

  if (loading) {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Loading...</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

  return (
    <FlatList
      data={messages}
      renderItem={({ item }) => <Text>{item.text}</Text>}
      keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
      inverted // This will start the list from the bottom, like most chat apps
    />
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the way that I solved a similar problem, when I had it, was:

```
import { ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
Import { getData } from '// other folder'; // it is the fetching function
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [hook, setHook] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const response = await getData(key); 
      if (response) {
      setHook(treatedResponse)
      setIsLoading(false);
      }
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  if (isLoading || !Hook) {
    return (
      <View style={unifiedStyles.container}>
        <ActivityIndicator />
         {/*loading screen*/}
      </View>
    );
  }else{
    return(
     {/* Normal screen*/}
    )
  }
```

Put it simply. You have 2 screens. One for the loading and another that only appears when you finish loading everything.
Keep in mind this is a very simple approach using only `useEffect` and `useState`. There are, probably, more optimized ways to go about it.